# Auto Completion problem in Android Studio giving error

Tags: android, kotlin

While writing Kotlin code in Android Studio it doesn't accept my Log.d and isn't giving me any complete options or anything. I have been stuck with auto complete for hours and I have tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>.

Comment: I would advice to add some code example into your question. It will increase the chances of getting an answer and reduce the chances of having your question flagged and removed.

Comment: Please show your work

Comment: sometimes Log.d won't work on some devices, I suggest you use Log.wtf() Instead